# nginx redirect rule, example.com/gaming/postName to g.example.com/postName

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to make 301 redirect rule because I moved my website domain.
My blog was running on
example.com/gaming
and posts are like this
example.com/gaming/postName

I want to rewrite it with a rule to be
G.example.com/postName
basically changing example.com/gaming -> g.example.com

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions for this problem and here's the one which I use.

```
server {  
              listen 80;
              server_name example.com;
              location /gaming {  
                           proxy_pass https://YOUR_APP_IP:3000;  
                           proxy_http_version 1.1;  
                           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
                           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';  
                           proxy_set_header Host $host;  
                           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;  
               }  
              location / {  
                           proxy_pass https://YOUR_APP_IP:3000;  
                           proxy_http_version 1.1;  
                           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;  
                           proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';  
                           proxy_set_header Host $host;  
                           proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;  
               }  
}
```

Here, keep `YOUR_APP_IP` as `127.0.0.1` if you're running on the same machine. else use the IP of the machine where your application is running.
This will route all the `/gaming` routes to default route.